# Not able to bind data in model class in C#.net, getting error while binding dynamic data to fields

Tags: c#, json, class

Hi i am not able to bind data in C# class fields..
getting error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".
this is my C# Class as below:

```
public partial class AccessCodeReqBody
    {
        [JsonProperty("scenarioKey")]
        public string ScenarioKey { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("destinations")]
        public Destination[] Destinations { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("whatsApp")]
        public WhatsApp WhatsApp { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Destination
    {
        [JsonProperty("to")]
        public To To { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class To
    {
        [JsonProperty("phoneNumber")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class WhatsApp
    {
        [JsonProperty("templateName")]
        public string TemplateName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("templateData")]
        public string[] TemplateData { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("language")]
        public string Language { get; set; }
    }
```

& the request json as below:

```
{
   "scenarioKey":"696BDB51C0ACF9E65B86D3E1D08A0084",
   "destinations":[
      {
         "to":{
            "phoneNumber":"919910666888"
         }
      }
   ],
   "whatsApp":{
      "templateName":"access_code",
      "templateData":[
         "Jennifer",
         "Demo",
         "123456"
      ],
      "language":"en"
   }
}
```

& the code for bind data in c# class as below where i am getting error on binding Phone number & template name :

```
            AccessCodeReqBody reqbody = new AccessCodeReqBody();
            reqbody.ScenarioKey = "51F5865AE296FAE86614EED";

           

            reqbody.Destinations.To.PhoneNumber = text1;
            reqbody.WhatsApp.TemplateName = "access_code";
            reqbody.WhatsApp.Language = "en";
            reqbody.WhatsApp.TemplateData = GetData(text2.ToString());
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: No reproduction https://dotnetfiddle.net/xqh4Fl. I have to issue deserializing with your class. May we have more information/context?  Your error message looks like a `NullReferenceException` "_Object reference not set to an instance of an object_", so where is the line causing it. And your title is about dynamic, and i see none

Comment: you didn't initialise `reqbody.Destination` ? `reqbody.Destination= new Destination[]{};`, you perhaps will need a list of Destination instead of an array if you want to Add.

Comment: if anyone has a dupe flag  [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/)

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the classes is correct. use this code

```
AccessCodeReqBody accessCodeReqBody = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessCodeReqBody>(json);
```

Comment: Thanks meysam asadi, But the issue i am getting to bind data in c# class field "Phone Number" & "templatename",i had edited my question for your reference.

Comment: I can not understand what you mean . Do you want to serialize? Or bind a phone number to templatename for what?

Comment: yes i want to bind phone number & template name, after bind the phone number & other data to c# class, i will convert this class to json..

Comment: Go to array/array element of this answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4660186/6560478. It has nothing to do with json. Your Error message is about `NullReferenceException`, and you forgot to initialise stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a simple enough solution

```
AccessCodeReqBody reqbody = new AccessCodeReqBody();
reqbody.ScenarioKey = "51F5865AE296FAE86614EED";

// Initialize your WhatsApp object. It is null if you don't
reqbody.WhatsApp = new WhatsApp();
//reqbody.Destinations.To.PhoneNumber = text1;
reqbody.WhatsApp.TemplateName = "access_code";
reqbody.WhatsApp.Language = "en";
reqbody.WhatsApp.TemplateData = GetData(text2.ToString());
```